# Dividing a string by spaces except when a specific character is met

Tags: java, string

I have a program that takes in a string and stores it in a string array. Before doing this, it divides the string by spaces and stores each into the index of the array.

However, I want the string to not separate by a space if a character, such as quotation marks, are present. As long as the string is inside of a quotation mark, it should store that entire substring in a string of its own in the array, even if it has spaces inside. To make it more clear, here is the command it parses:

```
AddGame 1001 "Mirror's Edge"
```

Where the first part is the command which is used as a switch for the switch case statements I have. The second is the game ID and the third is the name of the game. So far, when I make the game class and print it out, it returns:

```
(1001, "Mirror's)
```

While it should be:

```
(1001, Mirror's Edge)
```

I really don't want to use regex if possible. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Why not just limit your splitting to 2 maximum?  That way your resulting array will contain a maximum of 3 elements.  Is that what you want?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/StreamTokenizer.html

Comment: @LukePark There are also commands where there can contain 5 parts. There are multiple commands and those commands will determine the case.

Comment: @EricRangil You can implement an algorithm that splits the string according to command type.

Comment: Why not regex? Regex provides the smallest solution (one method call).

Comment: @EricRangil If you don't want a regex, you must implement your own split method.

Comment: If I were to implement a regex, would there be a way to make one regex that would work with all of the commands. Here are the possible commands (Hopefully I'm not asking for too much): AddGame 1002 "Dark Souls", AddAchievement 1001 901 "Access all areas" 20, AddPlayer 10001 "Bill Hamilton", AddFriends 10001 10002, Plays 10001 1001 "FaithRunner1337" and so on Or would I have to make a separate regex for each command?

Comment: Also @Bohemian not regex only because I don't have any experience with regex in java but I guess that's the only way to learn ayy?

Answer (score 1):

The "easy" way:

```
String[] array = str.split("\"?, *\"?(?=(([^\"]*\"){2})*[^\"]*$");
```

The "hard" way (pseudo code):

- Work your way along the input character by character
- Count the number of quotes encountered
- If the number is odd, do not treat commas as break points
- Ignore quotes for the purposes of collecting the parts
- Ignore any number of spaces after breaking commas

The regex version does all that.

Although the regex seems "hard", the amount of time and debugging spent implementing this manually makes the non-regex way "hard".

Answer (score -1):

It's simple when you store it in array use get line like this

Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

String s = in.nextLine();

Comment: This isn't what the OP wants.

Comment: This is what I am doing, however, I am making substrings using .split() by spaces. However, if it is in quotations, I want to store that as a whole string rather than dividing it by spaces. For example, AddPlayer 1001 "Jane Doe" should return (1001, Jane Doe) basing off of how my print function works, however, it returns (1001, "Jane)

Comment: @EricRangil did you look at StreamTokenizer? It's old and clunky but it handles quotes and does more or less exactly what you want.